# How to fix comments template in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am facing some problem in WordPress Comments template

In my WordPress I can see the comments template after every post but I don't want to see the headings like you can also use HTML tags.

So how can I remove that lines ?

Comment: Edit comments.php in the template folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply you need to put this code in comments.php page in you project

check `comment_form();` in that page & replace that code with this one

```
comment_form( array( 'comment_notes_after' => ' ', ) );
```